# How do I resolve "unsupported class file version 52.0" error in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Internet seems to think the problem is with the [source&target]Compatibility fields not being 1.7, but I changed that and can't seem to shake the error no matter what I do.

Running Android Studio 2.2.3 on Windows 10 from a imported Eclipse project. My configuration is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stuff.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-google-api-client.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev249-1.22.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev40-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

It seems to build fine normally from build-Make Project or build.gradle sync, but when I run or debug I eventually get the following error:

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html


AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"unsupported class file version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I even tried to up the RAM for the gradle JVM but my eclipse project doesn't seem to have a gradle.properties file, just a gradle-wrapper.properties and local.properaties. I'm new to Android Studio and Gradle so sorry if this is obvious.

The project build.gradle has the following in it:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

Messed with this a little too, but this seems to be the right plugin version vs the version that Android Studio uses which is 2.14.1. Slightly confused about these differences, but figure its useful info.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your java SDK version configured in IDE  project is behind SDK used to compile some of the libraries on your classpath . just configure proper one ( I would go for 1.8 )

Comment: I've tried changed the compatibility to 1.8 and adding support for Jake but this just results in errors in Java code for Lambdas

Comment: If lambdas are not suported, your JDK is not 1.8 You have to adjust as JDK version, as well as source level.

Comment: It has to do with using Jake, which is a requirement for targeting 1.8 in Android Studio. Give it a try instead of making statements that are incorrect. Also, have a look at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211386 to see why I have to stick with 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue. But my compileOptions is

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Error message is like yours

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"unsupported class file version     52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing     com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}
```

And the error said happened on paring `com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class`

I found out that `Beta.class` belonging to `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'`

So I removed the use of guava and the error is gone.
Hope this will help you.